# Client Side Localization of Image Button in DNN

Tags: localization, dotnetnuke

How do you localize an image button in DNN on the client side. I am using this method but it literal does not render

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="SubmitForm" OnClick="AddContactOrder" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="submit-button" ImageUrl='<%=LocalizeString("btnSubmit") %>' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of

```
LocalizeString("btnSubmit.ImageUrl",LocalResourceFile)
```

Where you have your ASCX file inheriting from PortalModuleBase and a RESX file View.ascx.resx in app_localresources (assuming you are using view.ascx). Inside that resx file you would define what btnSubmit.ImageUrl is.

Comment: DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.Localization.GetString("btnSubmit.ImageUrl",Loc‌​alResourceFile)